# Confused by pipes. 'cat -A' seems to filter out part of output

Tags: c++, bash

I am seeing this.

```
cat test.hs |./TonHospel 
25 x 25 matrix, 8 threads
permanent=-5258461839360 (0.213000 s)
user@user-desktop:~/python$ cat test.hs |./TonHospel |cat -A
25 x 25 matrix, 8 threads$
```

For some reason `cat -A` is filtering out part of the output. I guessed it might somehow be related to stderr and stdout so I tried piping both to stdout. This didn't help.

```
user@user-desktop:~/python$ cat test.hs |./TonHospel 2>&1 |cat -A
25 x 25 matrix, 8 threads$
```

Last I just randomly tried this.

```
user@user-desktop:~/python$ cat test.hs |./TonHospel 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 |cat -A
25 x 25 matrix, 8 threads
permanent=-5258461839360 (0.236000 s)
```

What is going on?  The C++ source code is at https://bpaste.net/show/ce5ca8643ba5 .

Comment: The program may be changing its output depending on whether or not stdout is a terminal.

Comment: What happens in `TonHospel`? Does it redirect?

Comment: It's C++ . I have the source here https://bpaste.net/show/ce5ca8643ba5 . I don't think it does anything strange does it?

Comment: Compare to `./TonHospel < test.sh > out.txt; cat -A out.txt`.

Comment: @chepner ./TonHospel < test.hs > out.txt; cat -A out.txt
25 x 25 matrix, 8 threads$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `quick_exit` at the end of `main`, rather than simply returning an exit code. That is extremely dangerous, as `quick_exit` does not bother to clean up the execution environment. In particular, it does not flush the buffer associated with `stdout`.

That won't be a problem if `stdout` is line-buffered, as it will be on most systems if it is attached to a terminal. But if it is fully buffered, as it will be if it is attached to a pipe, then output may be lost, which is what you are seeing.

That's not the only questionable programming practice in your code, but I believe it is the immediate problem.

(By the way, the first line is correctly printed because `std::cout << std:::endl;` explicitly flushes the `cout` buffer. Mixing c++ and c output functions is also a bad idea, though.)

Answer (score 0):

When `TonHospel` detects that its standard output is a terminal, it writes an additional line (such as `permanent=-5258461839360 (0.213000 s)`) to standard error. Nothing is written to standard error when standard out is something else, such as a pipe or a file.

Comment: That's a matter for a separate question. In any case, I am not sure the problem is in the code itself, but perhaps in how it is compiled or linked. It uses (in my opinion) an odd mix of `iostream` and `stdio`, and somehow the `printf` statements are writing to stderr and not stdout as I would expect. An actual C++ programmer would probably see something obvious that I am missing.

Comment: I've downloaded and compiled the OP's *TonHospel* (AKA *permanent*) code and find  that `echo foo | ./permanent` prints two lines; `echo foo | ./permanent | wc -l` returns *1*; and `echo foo | ./permanent > /dev/null` prints *nothing*, which seems odd if one of the lines was going to *stderr*.

Comment: @agc No, that's to be expected. All three cases print one line to standard output: the first to the terminal, the second to the pipe, and the third to a file. Only the first case has a terminal as stdout, so only the first case prints a line to stderr.